# Best way to extract text from a 1.3GB text file using PHP?

Tags: php, file

I have a 1.3GB text file that I need to extract some information from in PHP. I have researched it and have come up with a few various ways to do what I need to do, but as always am after a little clarification on which method would be best or if another better exists that I do not know about?

The information I need in the text file is only the first 40 characters of each line, and there are around 17million lines in the file. The 40 characters from each line will be inserted into a database.

The methods I have are below;

```
// REMOVE TIME LIMIT
set_time_limit(0);
// REMOVE MEMORY LIMIT
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
// OPEN FILE
$handle = @fopen('C:\Users\Carl\Downloads\test.txt', 'r');
if($handle) {
    while(($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $insert[] = substr($buffer, 0, 40);
    }
    if(!feof($handle)) {
        // END OF FILE
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Above is read each line at a time and get the data, I have all the database inserts sorted, doing 50 inserts at a time ten times over in a transaction.

The next method is the same as above really but calling `file()` to store all the lines in an array before doing a `foreach` to get the data? I am not sure about this method though as the array would essentially have over 17 million values.

Another method would be to extract only part of the file, rewrite the file with the unused data, and after that part has been executed recall the script using a `header` call?

What would be the best way in terms of getting this done in the most quick and efficient manner? Or is there a better way to approach this that I have thought of?

Also I plan to use this script with wamp, but running it in a browser while testing has caused problems with timeout even with setting script time out to 0. Is there a way I can execute the script to run without accessing the page through a browser?

Comment: For the last point, `php path/to/script.php` will execute the script.

Comment: @sarnold do I just do that from the command line? Thanks

Comment: Yes, right from the command line. You can also make it an executable script file if you intend on executing it often by adding `#!/path/to/php` on the first line of the script and then running `chmod 755 path/to/script` or `chmod 500` or whatever appropriate permissions you want.

Comment: How about condenses entire file by using some high level programming language like java, prepare each line with the data you need and then use PHP to add the data into database.

Comment: Open the file, use `fgetl` to read each line, do what you need, and loop like that. You won't be storing more than a line in memory at any point in time. It doesn't matter then how large the file is.

Comment: If doing this in PHP, you should use prepared statements and insert the data at the same time you read it. You could benchmark to see if it's beneficial to insert (e.g.) 1000 at a time using the extended insert syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have it good so far, don't use "file()" function as it would most probably hit RAM usage limit and terminate your script.

I wouldn't even accumulate stuff into "insert[]" array, as that would waste RAM as well. If you can, insert into the database right away.

BTW, there is a nice tool called "cut" that you could use to process the file.

```
cut -c1-40 file.txt
```

You could even redirect cut's stdout to some PHP script that inserts into database.

```
cut -c1-40 file.txt | php -f inserter.php
```

inserter.php could then read lines from php://stdin and insert into DB.

"cut" is a standard tool available on all Linuxes, if you use Windows you can get it with MinGW shell, or as part of msystools (if you use git) or install native win32 app using [gnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm).

Comment: Wouldn't that be too much for mysql to handle though? Doing one insert 17million times or 50 at a time? After inserting 50 the array is reset.

Comment: @Griff, it's PHP's array access vs MySQL insert speed. It could be faster, but it might be slower as well. The only way to check that would be to benchmark. Also, using prepared INSERT statement with only parameters changing could help.

Comment: Thank you for this information. Will get to work at it right away and let you know how I get on :)

Comment: Thanks this worked perfect, script has been running for 5 minutes and has inserted over 1 million rows, all I did different was to use the insert array and when it reach 600 do a multiple insert. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 2):

Why are you doing this in PHP when your RDBMS almost certainly has bulk import functionality built in? MySQL, for example, has [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt'
INTO TABLE `some_table`
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
  ( @line )
SET `some_column` = LEFT( @line, 40 );
```

One query.

MySQL also has the [`mysqlimport`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlimport.html) utility that wraps this functionality from the command line.

Comment: My shared host does not allow me to use `INFILE` it was my first choice.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above. The problem with the using `fgets()` is it does not work as you expect. When the maximum characters is reached, then the next call to `fgets()` will continue on the same line. You have correctly identified the problem with using `file()`. The third method is an interesting idea, and you could pull it off with other solutions as well.

That said, your first idea of using `fgets()` is pretty close, however we need to slightly modify its behaviour. Here's a customized version that will work as you'd expect:

```
function fgetl($fp, $len) {
    $l = 0;
    $buffer = '';
    while (false !== ($c = fgetc($fp)) && PHP_EOL !== $c) {
        if ($l < $len)
            $buffer .= $c;
        ++$l;
    }
    if (0 === $l && false === $c) {
        return false;
    }
    return $buffer;
}
```

Execute the insert operation immediately or you will waste memory. Make sure you are using [`prepared statements`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to insert this many rows; this will drastically reduce execution time. You don't want to submit the full query on each insert when you can only submit the data.

Comment: Is that still an issue since PHP 4.3.0? Also, how will the speed be with 76 times as many function calls?

Comment: I believe this is the expected behavior of fgets(). The speed should not be an issue if you are using prepared statements (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: @KSiimson I am using `PDO` prepared statements, @Wiseguy this is what I thought ommiting the `length` attribute will do as I wanted?

Comment: @Griff Right, omitting the `length` attribute and using `substr()` will give the same result. Using `fgetc()` as in my example will only be beneficial if the lines will be thousands of characters long or more. So unless your lines are huge, you are good to go!

Comment: @KSiimson Ye the lines are no more than 500 characters long, but I have saved this function it will be sure to come in handy! Thanks